# Do you need to be a certain level to enchant a certain level of magical item?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, rituals

I have a question about the wording in the Adventurers vault where it talks about enchanting items,

> The ritual caster must still be high enough level to create the final item...

The level it refers to, is that the players actual level or something else? And does that mean the item level cannot exceed that level?

Comment: Note Well: only *common* items may be enchanted these days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The General Rule is you can only enchant items up to your current level...**

From the Enchant Item ritual description:

> The new version must be your level or lower, and the component cost equals the difference in gold piece value between the old version and the new. -Players Handbook, p.304

**Exceptions exist however...**

The *Artificer* Class is all about making items and making them better/faster/cheaper than any other class.

For example, the **Master Crafter Feat**:

> When you use the Enchant Magic Item ritual to create a magic item, you can create a magic item of your level + your Intelligence modifier or lower.

And **Mark of Making [Dragonmark]**

> Benefit: You have mastered the Enchant Magic Item ritual and can perform it as if you were two levels higher.

Kudos to BrianS for the dragonmark suggestion.

Comment: I believe one of the Dragonmarks in the Eberron Player's Guide also lets you add +2 to your level for the purpose of enchanting/alchemy.

Comment: @BrianS will double-check via the compendium.